# Laravel 4 - How to redirect without subdomain parameter name in url

Tags: laravel-4

I need some assistance clarifying how to properly generate redirects in laravel when the subdomain of the url is being used as a parameter in the routing.

The route in question is as follows:

```
Route::group(array("domain"=>"{subdomain}.mydomain.com"),function(){
    Route::group(array("before"=>"auth"),function(){
        Route::get("logout",array("as"=>"logout",function(){
            Session::flush();
            Redirect::route("login");
        }));
    });
    Route::group(array("before"=>"guest"),function($subdomain){
        Route::get("login",array("as"=>"login",function($subdomain){
            return View::make('login'); 
        }));
    });
});
```

The "logout" route redirects to `http://dev.mydomain.com/http://%7Bsubdomain%7D.mydomain.com/login`

While I had anticipated:
`http://dev.mydomain.com/login`

When I remove the outer route group (the one grabbing the subdomain as a parameter), everything works as expected.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: There's a solution posted to the Laravel github "issues" section regarding this problem: https://github.com/laravel/laravel/issues/2515

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by using `Redirect::to('login')` instead of using named routes.
It only happens when using `Redirect::route('login')`.

Answer (score 0):

It may be related to your domain name. If you use local domain, you may use invalid character inside it such as "_", "+", "," etc.

Answer (score 0):

I've read countless articles about this issue in **Laravel 4**. Not one of the solutions worked for me. You cannot URL::to('login') and remove the subdomain when inside the subdomain. Laravel remembers it.

This is how you should "*get outside*" of the subdomain.

First you should **name the root route** and also define your main **domain**.

```
Route::group(['domain' => 'yourwebsite.com'], function()
{
    Route::get('/', ['uses' => 'YourController@getIndex', 'as' => 'home']);
});
```

Second you can **construct the route** by yourself:

```
URL::route('home').'/login'
```

That would be enough to resolve the L4 subdomain routing problem.

If you want to automatically redirect to the the non-subdomain URL. You can do this at the end of your subdomain handling:

```
Route::group(['domain' => '{subdomain}'.'.yourwebsite.com'], function() {

    // Here goes all your subdomain handling

    // Then handle subdomain requests that where not found
    Route::get('{slug}', function($subdomain, $slug) {
        return Redirect:to(URL::route('home').'/'.$slug);
    })->where('slug', '.*');
});
```